# When User clicks on any circle I want to show the below effect. Consider Pink color circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When User clicks on any circle I want to show the below effect. Consider Pink color circle.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yagI.png)

OnClick on any circle then I want to draw as shown in the image.

I could draw the circle using below code snippet:

```
<div className="tableRow">
                 {this.paletteColors.map((paletteColor) => {
                     return (<li className="color-li">
                         <div className="circle"
                             style={{
                                 "backgroundColor": paletteColor
                             }}
                             data-colorval={paletteColor}
                             onClick={this.paletteColorClick}
                         > </div>
                     </li>);
                 })}
             </div>

.color-li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0px 12px;
    line-height: 40px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It probably more a case of changing the circle to make it smaller and then adding a border rather than 'drawing a circle within a circle'. Is that what you're asking to do?

Answer (score 1):

A mixture of `box-shadow`, `background-clip` , `box-sizing:border-box` etc and a little Jquery can manage most of that:

```js
(function($) {
  $('.circle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgreen;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: border-width .3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
}
.circle.red {
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
.circle.open {
  border-width: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle red"></div>

<div class="circle blue"></div>
```